# logic app with service bus custom trigger

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to define custom trigger in Logic Apps? I want a trigger that will peek a SB Queue message (on the top) and check the `SystemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUTC`. Based on that it will perform some action. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you should show some attempts of yours, at least some thoughts about how non-custom triggers are created and why you don't know how to create a custom one

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a custom trigger. Just have simple service bus trigger that peeks first message. And have an action to check the `EnqueuedTimeUTC`, do whatever you need, and then don't forget to either complete the message or dead letter it.

There's even a template for it called `Peek-lock receive a Service Bus message with exception handling`.

The trigger is simple polling on `{your service bus}/messages/head/peek`